# Task based timeout, activating slower than expected

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, timeout, async-await, task

I have an HttpMessage, which at some point expects a result. I want the user to be able to await a task which returns ether after the response has been set, or after the timeout has elapsed. When running my unit tests, it works but only if i set the timeout much sooner than the delayed setting of the response.

Why is this happening, and is there anything I can do to tighten up the timing.

*Note the unit test below works, but if instead set the delay to 500ms, it fails

HttpMessage code:

```
public async Task<bool> ContinueWhenResponseRecieved(int Timeout)
        {
            NotifyTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            bool result = true;
            //If we have already recieved a response return true;
            if (this._response != null)
            {
                return result;
            }
            //If Timeout is not 0 then start a task that after the timeout period will set the completion source to true no matter what
            if (Timeout != 0) 
            {
                TaskEx.Run(async () =>
                {
                    await TaskEx.Delay(Timeout);
                    result = false;
                    try
                    {
                        NotifyTaskCompletionSource.SetResult(true);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { } //ignore race condition issues
                });
            }
            await NotifyTaskCompletionSource.Task;
            return result;
        }
        public override IHttpMessage setResponse(HttpResponse _response)
        {
            if (NotifyTaskCompletionSource != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    NotifyTaskCompletionSource.SetResult(true);
                }catch(Exception ex){} //Ignore race condtion issues
            }
            return base.setResponse(_response);
        }
```

Unit Test:

```
  [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestNotifiableTimeOuts()
    {
        var msg = new NotifiableHttpMessage();
        TaskEx.Run(() =>
        {
            TaskEx.Delay(1000).Wait();
            msg.setResponse(new Messages.HttpResponse());
        });
        var result= await msg.ContinueWhenResponseRecieved(50);

        Assert.IsFalse(result);
    }
```

Comment: There's no point in using asynchronous, rather than synchronous, methods if all you ever do is synchronously wait for them to finish.

Comment: @Servy Are you assuming that will be the case due to unit tests? You cant run a unit test async, so i just use .Wait() as a work around. In production a person would await ContinueWhenResponseRecieved(50) and it would be run asyncronously.

Comment: You should use a testing framework that *does* support asynchronous methods if you want to test asynchronous methods.  There are plenty of them out there.   That said, you're also performing synchronous actions in the non-test code as well.

Comment: @Servy Edited HttpMessage, still causes same issue. I would use a better testing framework if i wasnt working in a Windows Phone

Comment: @Servy You know what i didnt know msTest now supports asynchronous methods. Thanks for that. Question above is still a problem

Comment: @Servy Actually now that i have a fully flushed out async test, it works just fine. Thanks, The problem was that the unit tests were not async, if you make that an answer i will approve it.

Comment: Note that if neither Servy nor anyone else posts an actual answer, you can post and accept the answer yourself. This would be better than using the question to provide the answer.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Noted, i was waiting 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

**Credit To Servy**

The problem was that the unit test wasnt async, and was causing problems. A fully flushed out async test did the trick. End result unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
    public async Task TestNotifiableTimeOuts()
    {
        var msg = new NotifiableHttpMessage();
        TaskEx.Run(async () =>
        {
            await TaskEx.Delay(200);
            msg.setResponse(new Messages.HttpResponse());
        });
        var result= await msg.ContinueWhenResponseRecieved(50);

        Assert.IsFalse(result);
    }
```